# newbie - Best patterns and tools for a real asp.net mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, entity-framework-4.1

I'm studing how to build a mvc 3 web application and I am very confused. 
I spent the last few days reading about DDD, DI, IoC, TDD, EF (and tools like castle mapper, automapper, windsor, ecc) but I need your experience to make up my mind and choose a path to follow.

What I know:
 - I want to use MVC 3.0
 - I want to use EF 4.1 or 4.2
 - I don't want to use Unit Tests for the moment but I want the structure of my project to support them in the future with few modification.
 - I want to heavily use jQuery (the application need to be "very ajax")
 - I obviously don't want my controllers and views to directly use EF objects
 - I don't want to write duplicate code (ie: if I have a "person" db table with a "FirstName" property, I don't want to create a class for each layer of the software [dal, bll, ui, ...] with the same "person" data. Adding a field to the database should not need to add a property to way to many classes)

What I'd like to know:
 - Which pattern(s) would you use?
 - Best way of organizing projects inside the vs2010 solution?
 - Code first or database first?
Last but not least: Is it possible to use all the cool features of mvc (data annotation, validation, ecc) with a heavily ajaxed site?

Of course I don't expect a fully detailed answer: I just need some pointers/help/link to go in the right direction and study what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very broad.  May want to ask a more focused question.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that I am new to this world and I need some more info to understand which specific questions to ask. Maybe a book would be better than a SO question, but still some generic inputs would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Their is a book called "Test-Drive ASP .NET MVC" by the Pragmatic Programmers.  The ebook may be updated for MVC 3, but it would be a good place for you to start.  Also look at the NerdDinner application.  There is a free ebook for it too and lots of source code to look at.

Comment: If you go through all of the material at http://www.asp.net/mvc you should get a pretty good background.

Answer (score 1):

To describe your situation: You want to use a couple of frameworks and want to use as much of the best practices/patterns out there. You will fail. Your job is to build working software and not to use as much patterns as possible for your job.

Some "high level advice":

- DDD: don't do it! It does make sense in some projects but that often as people would think
- TDD: go for it to improve your design
- Patterns: When you have a solution for something or a design idea, check out if there is a pattern that describes that idea and not the other way round.
- Avoid some patterns: Singleton, facade under some conditions,...
- Take a look at SOLID and read [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Answer (score 0):

Well. I've seen a lot of overdesigned applications which makes maintenance a nightmare. I would advice you to start by just following [seperated interface pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/separatedInterface.html) and [Single Responsibility Principle](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/single-responsibility-prinicple/). Those two combined makes it easy to maintain and refactor code in future versions.

Unit testing is also a good thing. Not just to make sure that your application work, but to make you rethink your design. A class that is hard to test is most likely badly designed. The most common solution is to break down the class into smaller classes with more clear responsibilites.

I usually try to use blackbox testing when writing unit tests. That is to try to NOT look in the class that the tests are for. If I can't figure out how a class is working by looking at the contract (method definitions), I might have to refactor it.